# Changing parameter in PHP function and reload, using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

question about using AJAX here. I want to change the functions parameters and reload it.

So the function's initial value of $x might be 5, I want to change this by clicking a button, and reload the function but $x would equal 6. Etc.

```
<?php 
function first_Func($x,$y){
    //do this
}
```

This was suggested to me on my other question:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
        var x = '12';
        var y = '17'; 
        var url  = "url of the script";
        $.ajax({'url' : url ,
            'type' : 'post',
            'data' : {'x' : x , 'y' : y} ,
            'success' : function(data){
                // do something with your data
            }
        });
```

But I don't understand how this works. I am presumably passing data to the server, but how can I use this within my script? I'm not altering any variable within my original PHP script with this..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand: are you trying to change a function in your javascript or in your php?

Comment: In the PHP function just do `echo ++$x;` the last `echo` (I think it's the last) is what is returned in the AJAX `function(data)` so then just do something else with the data then... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to scroll through the months of a year, so I want to increment or decrement the variable that holds the current month, which is a parameter of my function.
So, I want to change my PHP script and reload it with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$result = ...
return json_encode($result);
```

Manage variables in the client-side (javascript). Declare a variable in the beginning and increase/decrease inside an onclick.

The `success` in jQuery is a `callback` - define what are you going to do with the data that PHP script has returned (e.g. put it inside a HTML tag with `getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = value`)

Comment: This is not recomended, $_POST is inject vulnerably

Comment: it depends on what is going to be done inside the AJAX script. For example, if it's a database query, you should protect your script from SQL injections

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this script to your own like this

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    var x = "$x";
    var y = "$y"; 
    var url  = "url of the script";
    $.ajax({'url' : url ,
        'type' : 'post',
        'data' : {'x' : x , 'y' : y} ,
        'success' : function(data){
            // do something with your data
        }
    });
```

If you have need to read from an form the script instead of `$x and $y` use these:
`filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` or `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` for reading them from an adress.

Comment: Is 'data' : changing the parameters of my original PHP function? Sorry, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Yes is changing, `'x'` will become `$x` and `y` `$y`

Comment: Okay this is still not working for me. I have a calendar function which takes variables $month and $year. This is in a separate file. I call the function in said file with calendar(date("m"),2013), below the function itself. 

It seems that this function call is over riding the function I'm trying to call with AJAX parameters. Does this make sense? So I need to initiate a function call with the variables stated in my AJAX request - but this isn't happening. The function is only taking the values I initially declare..

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP script have to catch the get variables x and y and pass it into the function. 
e.g.

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET["x"]) && isset($_GET["x"]) ) {
    echo test( $_GET["x"] , $_GET["y"] );

  }

function test($x, $y) {
    return json_encode(array( $x, $y));
}
```

but way to pass variables is very rought the way i did.

in javascript your success function looks like this

```
success:function (data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```